# xrandr: Add a virtual resolution?

Tags: nvidia, xrandr, resolution

I need to add a virtual resolution of 936x702.
It must use the physical 1024x768 resolution and only render to the central 936x702 area.
Is it possible?

I'm building an arcade machine with an old PC and an old CRT TV. The GPU is a GeForce 9500 GT. The TVOUT has overscan by default and it's impossible to adjust it on Linux.

Comment: as far as I can tell, only if either your card does that, or your screen does that. This **very** much sounds like an X/Y problem, though. What do you need that for?

Comment: I'm building an arcade machine with an old PC and an old CRT TV.
The GPU is a GeForce 9500 GT.
The TVOUT has overscan by default and it's impossible to adjust it on Linux. I've tried everything.

Comment: ah that's important info, especially about the CRT. Yeah, CRTs usually don't understand the "letterboxing" you're trying to achieve. The graphics card would have to do that. But that's not the graphics cards' job to define the size of a window. So, I don't think this will work out like this. I'm no X guru, but it sounds to me like you want to just change the size of the root window.

Comment: I can tweak openbox to reduce the desktop area, and I can tweak mednafen (using a custom scale), mame (using a black bezel), retroarch (adjusting scale manually or using a custom window size).
However, it's pretty cumbersome. I wanted a more general solution.
My current approach won't work for every game/emulator. When a game goes fullscreen, it just takes the whole screen. If only I could fool them with a fake resolution...